# C++ build error -- unique_ptr to shared_ptr

Tags: c++, clang

I am facing a weird issue during build, I have some C++ code which is used in an Android project using JNI wrapper. In the C++ code, I have a class T and an interface T_Interface.
T extends from T_Interface.

I am trying to call a method which expects `std::shared_ptr<T_Interface>` as a parameter.
My code has `std::unique_ptr<T> t` and I call the method with parameter `std::move(t)`

I am seeing the below error:

```
no viable conversion from '
remove_reference<unique_ptr<T, default_delete<T> > &>::type'
(aka 'std::__ndk1::unique_ptr<T, std::__ndk1::default_delete<T> >')
to 'std::shared_ptr<T_Interface>' T extends from T_Interface type
```

Code Sample:

```
std::unique_ptr<T> t = A::B::T::create(config);

std::shared_ptr<C::D::X> test =
        XYZ::create(
            config, customerDataManager, std::move(t), userInterfaceManager, nullptr, deviceInfo);

Error comes in std::move(t) parameter.

std::unique_ptr<PQR> XYZ::create(
    const P& configuration,
    std::shared_ptr<Blah> customerDataManager,
    std::shared_ptr<T_Interface> storage,
    std::shared_ptr<Blah> authRequester,
    std::shared_ptr<Blah> httpPost,
    std::shared_ptr<Blah> deviceInfo) {
}
```

Comment: std::move(t) converts unique_ptr to shared_ptr right? why is the error coming then?

Comment: It does not.  But a unique_ptr can be converted into a shared_ptr. How about a code sample?

Comment: Do you actually need shared_ptr? Unique_ptr should be preferred whenever possible.

Comment: @AndersK Please actually point (with your own finger) to a signature of `std::make_shared` that would accept a `std::unique_ptr` rvalue. Assume that no constructor of `T` exists that would accept such a thing here. Trying it in the real world is premature at best, given that it's an imaginary construct. You'd need to implement it first :) Why? Because `make_shared` works as follows: *The object is constructed as if by the expression `::new (pv) T(std::forward<Args>(args)...)`*. So, it won't work that way, and wasn't meant to work that way, and that's that. Surely you never tried...

Comment: @ReinstateMonica you are correct, i seemed to have remembered incorrectly.

Comment: Why does the error message say `std::__ndk1::unique_ptr`, but `std::shared_ptr` (without the `__ndk1::`?

Answer (score 0):

You're attempting to use the following `std::shared_ptr` constructor:

```
template< class Y, class Deleter > shared_ptr( std::unique_ptr<Y,Deleter>&& r );
```

And indeed, it works:

```
#include <memory>

struct Wrapper {
    Wrapper(const std::shared_ptr<int> &v) : value(v) {}
    std::shared_ptr<int> value;
};

std::unique_ptr<Wrapper> create(const std::shared_ptr<int> &ptr)
{
    return std::make_unique<Wrapper>(ptr);
}

int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<int> value = std::make_unique<int>(10);
    std::unique_ptr<Wrapper> wrapped = create(std::move(value));
}
```

But what you're using is slightly different: you're trying to do two things at once. You're not creating a `std::shared_ptr<T>` from `std::unique_ptr<T>`! You're trying to create a `std::shared_ptr<T_Interface>` from `std::unique_ptr<T>`. This should work as well, as long as you set the language standard high enough (e.g. gcc only accepts it with `--std=c++14` or higher, MSVC 2017 needs no special arguments).

```
#include <memory>

struct I_Wrapper {};

struct Wrapper : I_Wrapper {
    Wrapper(const std::shared_ptr<int> &v) : value(v) {}
    std::shared_ptr<int> value;
};

struct WrapperWrapper {
    WrapperWrapper(const std::shared_ptr<I_Wrapper> &w) : value(w) {}
    std::shared_ptr<I_Wrapper> value;
};

auto create1(const std::shared_ptr<int> &ptr)
{
    return std::make_unique<Wrapper>(ptr);
}

auto create2(const std::shared_ptr<I_Wrapper> &ptr)
{
    return std::make_unique<WrapperWrapper>(ptr);
}

int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<int> value = std::make_unique<int>(10);
    std::unique_ptr<Wrapper> wrapped = create1(std::move(value));
    std::unique_ptr<WrapperWrapper> wrappedWrapped = create2(
        std::move(wrapped)
    );
}
```

So maybe you're using a very old compiler. But this works just fine with anything reasonably recent on godbolt. You're probably not telling us something. At minimum you'd need to:

1. Create an actual minimal example that is meant to compile and has dummy methods and types that match the signatures of the types you use.
2. Double check that the example doesn't compile, and the compilation fails with the same error.
3. Provide the exact command line used to invoke the compiler (e.g. pass `-DVERBOSE_MAKEFILE=YES` to cmake).
4. Provide the exact version of the compiler, and the platform it runs on.

Answer (score -3):

That is to be expected.  You really shouldn't be able to automatically convert `unique_ptr` to `shared_ptr`; the ownership models are sufficiently different that that conversion will be the wrong choice more often than not.

Try using `std::shared_ptr(t.release())` or `std::shared_ptr(std::move(t))` instead:  the explicit conversion tells the reader what you're actually doing.

Comment: This has no reflection in the design of `std::shared_ptr`. Creating a shared pointer from a unique pointer rvalue is perfectly valid, and it's almost never a wrong choice. The only reason for release's existence is legacy API interoperability. If you're creating any sort of a smart pointer from the return value of `std::unique_ptr::release`, you're doing something quite wrong: either the smart pointer you're using is braindead, or you're going about it the wrong way.

Comment: Well, then, explain why does `shared_ptr` has a non explicit constructor that takes a `unique_ptr`, if such a conversion is wrong?

Comment: I don't think using `unique_ptr::release` is any better (or any worse) than using `std::move` (I have edited my answer to include the latter).  And I certainly didn't imply that converting between the two was wrong:  only that you shouldn't be able to do it by accident..